# How to use PUT method based on particular card-id in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, axios

in my dashboard it displays some cards which contains data and it displayed like card (these cards are contained data which  are coming from backend api and bind to cards before binds it stores into an array called notes[]),if i click on any particular displayed card it should opens one pop-up it's called an updatecard based on id it opens but  i am unable to connect uppdateNote.vue to the backend api(PUT-method), and my updateNote is worked based on id of a particular card[this is my api-url of put method http://localhost:8000/api/updateNote/{id}] little bit confusion how to pass particular clicked card id into an updateNote url id, please help me to fix this issue [[url hitting is not correct it shows some different id,my hitting api url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mwg5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mwg5.png)

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section" >
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id"  id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle(note.id)" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes :cardId="clickedCard"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
           clickedCard:'',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(id){
            var blur=document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');
             this.clickedCard = id;

            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');

        },
        // myIndex(){
        //     document.getElementById('blur').innerHTML=this.notes.findIndex();
        // }

    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

`UpdateNotes.vue`

```
<template>
 <div  class="update" >
        <form class="update-note" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit" autocomplete="off">
            <input name="title"  v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
            <textarea name="content" v-model="body" style="resize: none" placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3"></textarea>
            <div class="btm-icons">
                <icons />
                <button id="btn-section"  type="submit" @click="handlesubmit" >Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import icons from './icons.vue'
import service from '../service/User'
export default{
    components:{icons},
    props: ['cardId'],
     data() {
        return {
            title:'',
            body:''
        }
    },
    methods:{
     async handlesubmit(){
       let userData={
id:this.cardId,
title:this.title,
body:this.body
       }
        service.userUpdateNotes(userData).then(response => {
         localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.token);  
               alert("Note updated  successfully");
               return response;
            })
     }
    }
}

</script>
<style scoped>
.update {
  padding-top: 0%;
  
}

.update-note {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 152px auto;
  margin-right: 80%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #ccc;
}
.update-note input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

[maintains methods of api calls]
`axios.js`

```
// npm install axios --save
//axios.defaults.baseURL="http://localhost:8000/api"

import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL=process.env.VUE_APP_AXIOS_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer'+ localStorage.getItem('token');

export default class AxiosService{
   postData(url,data){
       return axios.post(url,data).then(response =>{
           return response;
       }).catch(error=>{
           return error;
       })
   }
   getData(url){
        return axios.get(url).then(response=>{  
            localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.token);  
            return response;
       }).catch(error=>{
            return error;
       })
   }
   updateData(url,data){
       return axios.put(url,data).then(response=>{
           return response;
       })
   }
}
```

[which contains url of backend api and calling method from axios.js]
`user.js`

```
// import axios from 'axios';
import AxiosService from '../service/axios';
const axios=new AxiosService()

export default{
    userRegister(data){
        return axios.postData("/register",data);
    },
    userLogin(data){
        return axios.postData("/login",data);
    },
    userForgot(data){
        return axios.postData("/auth/sendPasswordResetLink",data);
    },
    userReset(data){
        return axios.postData("/auth/resetPassword",data);
    },
    userCreateNote(data){
        return axios.postData("/createNote",data);
    },
    userDisplayNotes(){
        return axios.getData("/displayNotes");
    },
    userUpdateNotes(data){
        //my actual url is http://localhost:8000/api/updateNote/1 (id= id of my card)
        return axios.updateData("/updateNote/${id}",data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `userUpdateNotes` function to `return axios.updateData("/updateNote/${data.id}",data);`, as you are passing data in the method and not the id, so if you want to access the id it should be accessed using `data.id`.

Also use backticks(`) instead of using double-quotes(").

Comment: Hello  @Yash Maheshwari, Thank you so much it's working fine ,and one small error  when ever i clicked on close btn in popup the update request goes two times to backend

Comment: In popup means in the `UpdateNote` component? Also, like on a single click it sends two request?

Comment: ,yeah in updateNote component if i click on close button ,it should hits the api two time but i need that thing in one time

Comment: Ok, got it, you are calling the `handleSubmit` twice. One in the form submit event and another on the close button click event. Remove one of the calls.

Comment: Change `@submit.prevent="handlesubmit"` to this `@submit.prevent`.